# Difficulty with EncFS on CentOS

Tags: ubuntu, centos, encryption, encfs

I'm trying to figure out `encfs`, but am having some difficulty.

This is what I have done so far:

I created 2 test folders

```
mkdir /home/oshiro/Desktop/encrypted
mkdir /home/oshiro/Desktop/decrypted
```

The difficulty is that the next command gives me a `permission denied` message:

```
encfs /home/oshiro/Desktop/encrypted /home/oshiro/Desktop/decrypted
```

When I run that command in Ubuntu 12.04, it works perfectly and both folders work correctly, i.e. I can create files folders in the `decrypted` folder, and they appear in the `encrypted` folder automatically etc.

However, when I try to run that command in CentOS 6.5, I get a `permission denied` error.  When I add `sudo` infront of that command, it mounts the `decrypted` folder as normal, but I can't open the folder as a normal user, I get a `permission denied` error.

On Ubuntu 12.04, I don't need to use `sudo` to run `encfs`.  How do I run that command without `sudo` on CentOS 6.5, or is that unsafe?  If it's unsafe, how to I mount that folder so I can access that folder by the user logged in?

Here is the full error I get when I try to run `encfs` on CentOS 6.5 without `sudo`:

```
[oshiro@centos- ~]$ encfs /home/oshiro/Desktop/encrypted /home/oshiro/Desktop/decrypted
EncFS Password: 
fuse: failed to exec fusermount: Permission denied
fuse failed. Common problems:
- fuse kernel module not installed (modprobe fuse)
- invalid options -- see usage message
[oshiro@centos ~]$
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by running the following command before mounting:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/fusermount
```

Comment: This creates a possibly security hole, see the answer below for a proper way of resolving this problem.

Answer (score 6):

You really just need to add your user 'oshiro' to the 'fuse' group. Then you won't need to reduce the overall system security by allowing *anyone* to run fusermount.

```
useradd -G fuse oshiro
```

Then either log out and back in, or run

```
exec /bin/bash
```